# Validation loss increasing immediately as training starts

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm training model to based on 8000 inputs predict vector of 20 outputs, where every element of both of the vectors are binary. Current model architecture is as following:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(8000, activation='relu', input_shape=(8000,), kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

I'm using SGD optimizer with `learning_rate=0.1` and `momentum=0.9`. The loss function is `binary_crossentropy` from `keras.losses.binary_crossentropy`, and model is trained on batch size of 512.[image: Loss on epoch graph]

[image: Accuracy on epoch graph]

The validation loss immediately shoots as the training begins. Any idea why it happens? I tried different learning rates, losses, and applying normalization and dropout differently but without any noticeable effect. Results of this model on separate test dataset are as follows:

```
TP: 318378
TN: 20708
FP: 61682
FN: 55232
Accuracy: 0.743
```

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT 1:**

Having useful comments to the question, I've changed the model to:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(8000, activation='relu', input_shape=(8000,), kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

    keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

And the optimizer to:
`optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)`

Batch size was reduced to 128. Results are as following:[image: Accuracy after change]
[image: Loss after change]

```
TP: 334313
TN: 16027 
FP: 45747 
FN: 59913
Accuracy: 0.768
```

Comment: You're using a very large batch size, which leads to small number of updates to your parameters, and hence less learning. I suggest trying smaller batch sizes, for example, 96 or 128. It might also be that you have a small training set.

Comment: From my point of view, I think the model is overparameterized so that overfits the training set easily. I would suggest reducing the number of parameters in your network. Also, using a smaller learning rate will help.

Comment: Why the `binary_crossentropy` loss with a 20-node sigmoid final layer? Is it a multiclass multi-label problem?

Comment: I've decreased the batch size to 128, and the results for validation set are still similar. The training set has over 100k samples. Also decreased the complexity of the model to only 2 hidden layers, one with batch normalization and one with dropout, yet problem remains. @desertnaut it's a multi-label classification, trying to predict binary vector with various combinations.

Comment: @ErnestPokropek The first layer contains 8000*8000+8000 parameters, which is a tremendous number of parameters. You can use model.summary() to see the total number of parameters. Try to start with a really small one and probably use Adam with lr =0.001. Last, is there any data imbalance issue in your dataset?

Comment: @twcmchang thanks for the suggestion. There is barely any imbalance in the data, since it was generated artificially. Could you give any idea how to decrease the number of parameters? I tried using 1D convolution layer for input (with 64 filters and kernel size 3), but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Using 1D convolution is a good alternative to reduce number of parameters. Or reduce the number of neurons in the first layer. BTW, is the usage of 'relu' in the first layer okay for binary inputs? It probably leads to zero gradients (no updates) for the weights with input value 0. Maybe change to sigmoid for the first layer. Just a random guess.